# How does hashem tell you if you really are fit to learn kabalah

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

How does one know if one is really fit to learn kabala. As we all know one has to be on a high madrega before learning it and it is not for everyone. So how can one know if he really is on the madrega. This question is not how to become fit for learning kabala like its so called duplicate, but how hashem is communicating with him and telling him if he is fit or not. According to the gemoro yuma hashem communicates with him in a practical way and tells him now you are fit or now you are unfit. In other words something practical (not in the mind) happens to the person if he is fit, and something else if he is unfit.

I can only repeat this is not a duplicate and since you consider it to be, the system does not allow me to answer. I assure you that the answer is of great interest.

Since I am not yet being allowed to answer perhaps I can broaden the question giving a similar example of where hashem tells you he 'doesnt' want you and how he tells you.

This is something I am sure everyone knows and that is hashem has his way of making sure you know that he doesnt like your succah for instance. Hashem shows this to you in a very practical way where you have no choice but to accept that he just doesnt want your succah.

The answer to my question when given the chance will be something very similar.

Considering as I have already mentioned it is a 'nigla' gemoro in yuma, and since so far no one has come up with it I doubt if anyone on here is really already fit to learn kabala!

I am going to ask another question which I hope will not be duplicated and then be able to answer it there.

Comment: @ray, I already commented there. But I think this is a different question. Hashem has a 'pratical' way of telling you if you are not up to learning kabala. You will have to wait seven hours according to the rules here before I can tell you what the gemoro says it is. In the meantime maybe others can tell us.

Comment: @ray, This is not a riddle at all.

Comment: what kind of signs did you have in mind regarding Hashem "telling you" you're ready.

Comment: @5730 If you know the answer to this question, why didn't you self-answer? Anyway, I agree that this *does* seem like a bit of a riddle question. It's the kind of question that one wouldn't ask unless he already knew the answer.

Comment: @Daniel Is the concurrent self answer option available to unregistered users?

Comment: @DoubleAA Don't know. I'm not sure why it wouldn't be, but I guess maybe it's not.

Comment: @ray I can only tell you the 'sign' in the answer. Since you are interested in learning kabala I am sure my answer will be of great interest to you. Do you still consider this a duplicate question? If not please amend it. The rules on here are, I cannot answer before seven hours so you will have to wait or change them.

Comment: @ray I now notice that since its considered a duplicate I am not able to answer. So please take off the duplication if you want my answer which I assure you is of great interest.

Comment: I am not a moderator.

Comment: @5730 you can 1. add it as a comment or 2. add it as an answer to the other question. As a side point, only msh210 (or other people who have a ♦ can remove the duplication).

Comment: @Shmuel ...or a group of 5 users with 3k rep.

Comment: @DoubleAA Can we override a mod? I know we can't vote for undeletion against mods.

Comment: @Shmuel I'm pretty sure you can for (un)closing things.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin We can vote for reopening. Most questions on here get closed by a mod because in a small community, it's unlikely that 5 non-mod 3k+ users will see a question before a mod does. It works the same way with re-opening, though. Once one person votes to reopen, the question goes to the reopen review queue and a mod usually sees it and reopens (if it's worthy of being reopened) before 5 people vote. I'm not suggesting that this question should be reopened, though.

Comment: This question has already moved elsewhere so there is no point in re-opening.